# intercept restful API with cypress in a ssr next.js project using axios

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, cypress, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to write some tests with cypress and fixtures on my ssr next.js app that connects to restful api using axios.
But I'm having trouble intercepting the restful apis using `cy.intercept()` because cypress can not track the requests that are sent in ssr and `cy.intercept()` only works on requests that cypress can track.
Is there any packages that can help me change the responses coming from restful api?

Comment: Please refer to [Control Next.js Server-Side Data During Cypress Tests](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/control-nextjs-data-during-tests/)